# Gradle Multiproject vs Android flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I'm trying to create two android applications that has common code, so I was documenting on Gradle Flavor and multiproject.

**Restrictions on project:**

- `App-A` and `App-B` depends on `common`
- `App-A` and `App-B` doesn't know each other.
- `App-A` will have some feature that doesn't exist on `App-B` and `common`
- `App-B` will have some feature that doesn't exist on `App-A` and `common`
- `App-A` and `App-B` will have its own `AndroidManifest.xml`

I’m trying to use MVP design pattern as well, I don’t know if it’ll have any incidence on the project.

I was thinking of using an architecture that would look like this.

```java
|--- Common
        |--- src
            |--- main
            |   |--- java
|--- App-A
        |--- src
            |--- main
            |   |--- java // For specific code
|--- App-B
        |--- src
            |--- main
            |   |--- java // For specific code
```

**Use Case:**
For example, I need to add a feature on `MainActivity` of `AppA`. Can I just extend/implement a class/interface on App-A to add this feature or do I have to copy everything from `MainActivity` of `main`?

I saw some advice about using `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` as it is available and can do the distinction between flavor, however I've noticed by reverse engineering a sample I made that it creates both MainActivity.

[image: Screenshot 2020-02-21 at 17.06.03|538x274, 50%]

Should I be worried about the size of my APK getting much bigger by using flavor ?

What would you recommend me to do ?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you organized the source code when using flavors. That is, did you put the flavor-specific code in the flavor-specific source directories (e.g. `src/flavorA/java`, `src/flavorB/java`, etc)?

Comment: Yes each `src/flavorA/java` and `scr/flavorB/java` has its own flavor-specific code, the code common to both is in `scr/main/java`